# Alternative to LayerDrawable.SetPadding on android 5

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've been using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827289/15186) to create a custom picker in Xamarin.Forms running on Android.

But it fails at runtime on devices with Android 5.1 on the call to SetPadding.

> NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable;.setPadding

Is there an alternative for what seems to have been introduced in Android 6 (API 23)?

EDIT: Fixed the link to the failing code.

Comment: Did you use the code correctly ? I saw it is `ShapeDrawable.SetPadding`, but the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable#setPadding(android.graphics.Rect)) is available from API1 .

Comment: Sorry it is on line 36. Fixed the link.

Comment: Do you mean line 36 causes the error? but is does not match the error message . In addition , I test the code on Android 5.1 , no error happens..

Comment: Sorry again, I may have used a variation of this code :(
The question remains though.

Comment: Please post your code so that i can test on my side .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I have fixed the link in the question. It leads to another SO answer. Look at the section titled 'Last is the full solution code of above two problems:' to find the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass inherit from LayerDrawable , override the getter method of  `BottomPadding` , `TopPadding` , `LeftPadding` , `RightPadding` , though it's not a smooth solution ..

```
 public class MyLayer : LayerDrawable
    {
        public MyLayer(Drawable[] layers):base(layers)
        {
            
        }

        public override int BottomPadding
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }       
        }

        public override int TopPadding
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }
        }

        public override int LeftPadding 
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }
        }

        public override int RightPadding 
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    }


  public MyLayer AddPickerStyles(string imagePath)
    {
        ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
        border.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
        border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        border.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

        Drawable[] layers = { border, GetDrawable(imagePath) };
        MyLayer layerDrawable = new MyLayer(layers);
        layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return layerDrawable;
    }
```